# Anemo elemental absorption and application

Tags: genshin-impact

Some anemo skills can absorb elements (pyro / hydro / electro / cryo), like Sucrose's burst, Venti's burst, Kazuha's burst, and Anemo Traveller's skill and burst (if I miss some, let me know)

The skill itself then deals anemo damage + elemental damage of the absorbed element

So, for example, we have a Venti that absorbed pyro and is then doing anemo + pyro + swirl damage with his burst to enemies caught into it

I kind of see what two of the inflicted damage scales off:

- Anemo damage scales off his atk + anemo dmg bonus%
- Swirl damage scales off his level and his elemental mastery

For some reason, when I see the damage of the absorbed element, it looks like it deals the same amount of damage as his anemo damage (this is not sure, I may want to test that later)

But the main question I want to ask here is, if he were to trigger/enable other elemental reactions using his infused burst, what is the ICD of the elemental application from it? Would it swirl immediately after or can it be used by other party members to react on?

**Edit**

From the comment, it is stated that ICD is skill specific, so I'm going to specify here, that I am asking for the ICD of Venti's burst specifically, and maybe rephrasing the question

Can the absorbed element (pyro here) be used to enable (apply pyro on mob) or trigger (apply pyro on a mob affected by hydro / cryo / electro / dendro) an elemental reaction or does it get consumed by Venti's swirl right away?

Comment: Swirl itself applies the given element in a 6m radius, and that's a one-timer. Until the next swirl. So after swirl, the enemies have the infused element applied. Can you please give a concrete example what ICD you mean? The ICN between Ventis anemo procs? ICD is skill-specific. The element absorbed also stays the same, even if you add others later.

Comment: got it, I'll base it on Venti's burst ICD solely

Comment: @prout try having a look [here](https://library.keqingmains.com/evidence/combat-mechanics/elemental-effects/transformative-reactions#swirl)  - I assume you want to focus on the swirl reactions chains.

Comment: @Ꮢedacted it is very related... now, I'm going to search what Venti's gauge unit per burst tick is